# AngularJS 2 - service error

Tags: angular

I am doing something wrong with my simple service but I can not figure it out.

app.component.ts

```
import { MeetingService } from '../../shared/services/meeting.service';

@Component({
  viewProviders: [MeetingService],
})
```

meetingService.ts

```
@Injectable();

export class MeetingService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getList() {
    return this.http.get('../fake-data/meetingList.json')
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

meetingList.component.ts

```
import { MeetingService } from '../../shared/services/meeting.service';

@Component({
  viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MeetingService],
})

export class MeetingListComponent {
  private meetingList: any;

  constructor(private meetingService: MeetingService) {}

  getList() {
    this.meetingService.getList().subscribe(
      data => { this.meetingList = data; },
      err  => console.error(err),
      ()   => console.log('done loading meeting list')
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getList();
  }
}
```

Error

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'MeetingService'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'MeetingService' is decorated with Injectable.
```

Can somebody take a look at it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `;` after `@Injectable()`

```
@Injectable()
export class MeetingService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getList() {
    return this.http.get('../fake-data/meetingList.json')
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: `;` means statement finished.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your bootstrap code - did you add `Http` to your application providers during bootstrap, e.g.,

```
bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS])
```